# why piping pwd and echo does not work?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, echo, pwd

I'm new to unix. I typed this command in ubuntu terminal:

```
pwd | echo
```

I expected to see the output of `pwd` in terminal(`/home/fatemeh/Documents/Code/test`)
 but the output was just ***a single empty line***.

why this happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`echo` does not do anything with standard input; it only parses its parameters.  So you are effectively running `echo` which, by itself, outputs a single empty line, and the standard input is discarded.

If you want to see the behavior you are trying to implement, use a tool designed to parse standard input, such as `cat`:

```
$ pwd | cat
/home/username
```

If you really want to use `echo` to display the current working directory (or the output of another command), you can use Command Substitution to do this for you:

```
$ echo "Your shell is currently working in '$(pwd)'."
Your shell is currently working in '/home/username'.
```

Answer (score 3):

As is stated in the other answers, `echo` does not read from stdin so it will not print the output of `pwd`.  Just in case you don't know already, `pwd` prints it's output on it's own so you simply need to run it alone to get your desired result.

```
$ pwd
/current/working/dir
```

If you really want to use echo for this you can use [Command Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03).  This will pass the output of your command (`pwd`) to `echo` as a parameter.  Which again in this example is not necessary as `pwd` will output it's own...output to stdout.

```
$ echo "$(pwd)"
/current/working/dir
```

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` command doesn't read from standard input, it writes what you tell it to write.  In this case, you didn't tell it to write anything, so all it printed was a newline.  `pwd | echo` is equivalent to just running `echo`.

If you want to use a pipe, then you need to use some command that reads from standard input (e.g., `cat`):

```
$ pwd | cat
/path/to/current/directory
$
```